# Add line break within tooltips

Tags: html, tooltip, newline

How can line breaks be added within a HTML tooltip?

I tried using `<br/>` and `\n` within the tooltip as follows:

```
<a href="#" title="Some long text <br/> Second line text \n Third line text">Hover me</a>
```

However, this was useless and I could see the literal text `<br/>` and `\n` within the tooltip. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: I 've had the same question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320081/how-does-stack-overflow-display-tooltip-for-the-questions

Comment: use <pre>data-html="true"</pre>
Ref and thanks to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19001875/2278891

Comment: In asp.net (C# .NET 4.5 Framework) adding `Environment.NewLine` works to add a line break from the code side... no fuss.. no muss...

Comment: The answer below, by Dan works perfectly. It is assing in the CSS for that element the line white-space as following:  `.tooltip-inner {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}`

Answer (score 353, accepted):

Just use the entity code `&#013;` for a linebreak in a title attribute.

Comment: if entity code &#013; doesn't work, try &#10; i am using linux and chrome not sure about other browsers

Comment: I tried this and it works when I inject it using inspect element, but not when I include it in my html and deploy it with this character. Any obvious reason I might be missing?

Comment: For me `&#10` din't work for me in Windows, Chrome v53. But `&#013;` worked fine.

Comment: I just used both versions, `&#013;&#010;`, seems to work quite well :)

Comment: &#013; doesn't work in Firefox v58. However &#10 does work fine. Using @Phe0nix solution of using both line-breaks as required works well to get it to work in Chrome, Microsoft Edge and Firefox.

Comment: Does not work in IE, and neither does &#010.  Why do browsers suck so bad that nobody can ever provide a real answer to questions like this?

Comment: This does not work if title attribute is dynamically set using javascript

Comment: both codes didnt work in my asp.net webform application, this method resolved the requirement.    `data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="some string <br/> some string"`

Comment: Neither &#013; or &#010; worked for me...but the suggestion from Pranesh worked great.  data-html="true" + <br /> = FTW

Comment: I had to add `data-bs-html="true"`.

Answer (score 116):

Just add a data attribute

> data-html="true"

and you're good to go.

Eg. usage:

```
<i data-html="true" class="tooltip ficon-help-icon" twipsy-content-set="true" data-original-title= "<b>Hello</b> Stackoverflow"> </i>
```

It has worked in majority of the tooltip plugins i have tried as of now.

Comment: data-html="true" with <br /> in title text works perfectly.

Comment: None of the above solutions worked for me. But this one works nice.

Comment: I believe there is a missing ">" just before  "</i>"   I tried to edit myself, but the 'edit queue' is full.

Comment: Doesn't this require bootstrap? OP was using `<title>`

Comment: Didn't work to me. Angular 10.

Comment: I had to add `data-bs-html="true"`.

Answer (score 70):

The `&#013;` combined with the style **white-space: pre-line;** worked for me.

Comment: I spent a while trying to get this to work. The fact that the `white-space: pre-line;` style is needed is very hidden.

Comment: @JimD what class/element does the style rule need to be applied to?

Comment: For me this works fine without any custom css on tooltips.

Comment: This is the one you are looking for friends.

Comment: Actually, the character should be `&#010;`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502054/web-tooltip-universally-accepted-linebreak-character

Comment: The pre-line did the trick, but it only worked for me with &#10;

Answer (score 40):

This CSS is what finally worked for me in conjunction with a linefeed in my editor:

```css
.tooltip-inner {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Found here:
[How to make Twitter bootstrap tooltips have multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338780/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-tooltips-have-multiple-lines)

Comment: @Dan Came here looking for help. My tooltip text was continuing outside the box. This worked! +1

Answer (score 19):

```
\n
```

with the styling

```
.tooltip-inner {
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

worked for me.

Comment: `\n` is to be used in javascript, for HTML we should use `&#10;` or `&#13;` or both

Answer (score 12):

Give `\n` between the text. It work on all browsers.

```
Example 
img.tooltip= " Your Text : \n"
img.tooltip += " Your text \n";
```

This will work for me and it's used in code behind.

Hope this will work for you

Answer (score 8):

I found it. It can be done by simply doing like this

```
<a ref="#" title="First Line
                  Second Line
                  Third line">Hover Me</a>
```

Answer (score 7):

just use \n in title and add this css

```
.tooltip-inner {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`&lt;br /&gt;` did work if you are using qTip

Answer (score 5):

## The javascript version

Since `&#013;` (html) is `0D` (hex), this can be represented as `'\u000d'`

```
str = str.replace(/\n/g, '\u000d');
```

#### In addition,

Sharing with you guys an **AngularJS filter** that replaces `\n` with that character thanks to the references in the [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9118551/3191896)

```
app.filter('titleLineBreaker', function () {
    return function (str) {
        if (!str) {
            return str;
        }

        return str.replace(/\n/g, '\u000d');
    };
});
```

usage

```
<div title="{{ message | titleLineBreaker }}"> </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use bootstrap tooltip, and don't forget to set the html option to true.

```
<div id="tool"> tooltip</div>
```

```
$('#tool').tooltip({
     title: 'line one' +'<br />'+ 'line two',
     html: true
});
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Just add data-html="true"

```
<a href="#" title="Some long text <br/> Second line text \n Third line text" data-html="true">Hover me</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

For me, a 2-step solution (combination of formatting the title and adding the style) worked, as follows:

1) Format the `title` attrbiute:

```html
<a ref="#" title="First Line
                  Second Line
                  Third line">Hover Me</a>
```

2) Add this style to the `tips` element:

```css
white-space: pre-line;
```

Tested in IE8, Firefox 22, and Safari 5.1.7.

Comment: I think it's messy though, to have broken lines in the code

Comment: What is the "tips" element?

Answer (score 2):

it is possible to add linebreaks within native HTML tooltips by simply having the title attribute spread over mutliple lines.

However, I'd recommend using a jQuery tooltip plugin such as Q-Tip: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/.

It is simple to set up and use. Alternatively there are a lot of free javascript tooltip plugins around too.

edit: correction on first statement.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the entity code `&#xA;` for a linebreak in a title attribute.

```html
<a title="First Line &#xA;Second Line">Hover Me </a>
```

Answer (score 2):

So if you are using bootstrap4 then this will work.

```
<style>
   .tooltip-inner {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
   }

</style>

<script> 
    $(function () {
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
    })
</script>

<a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="auto" title=" first line &#010; next line" href= ""> Hover me </a>
```

If you are using in Django project then we can also display dynamic data in tooltips like:

```
<a class="black-text pb-2 pt-1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="auto"  title="{{ post.location }} &#010; {{ post.updated_on }}" href= "{% url 'blog:get_user_profile' post.author.id %}">{{ post.author }}</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are using **Jquery Tooltip utility**, then in "jquery-ui.js" Javascript file find following text:

```
tooltip.find(".ui-tooltip-content").html(content);
```

and put above that

```
content=content.replace(/\&lt;/g,'<').replace(/\&gt;/g,'>');
```

I hope this will also work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this code snippet in your script:

```
    $(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
    });
```

and ofcourse as mentioned in above answers the `data-html` should be `"true"`. This will allow you to use html tags and formatting inside the value of `title` attribute.

Comment: +1, Your solution worked . my sample code:  `data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="some string <br/> some string"` .

Comment: Good to hear that 

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/:

And here the code (the part of script that make `<br/>` Works  is "content:"):

HTML HEAD

```
<head runat="server">
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    /*Position:
      my =>  at
      at => element*/
    $(function () {
        $(document).tooltip({
            content: function() {
                var element = $( this );
                if ( element.is( "[title]" ) ) {
                    return element.attr( "title" );
                }

            },
            position: { my: "left bottom-3", at: "center top" } });
    });
</script>
</head>
```

ASPX or HTML control

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Establecimiento" runat="server" Font-Size="1.3em" placeholder="Establecimiento" title="Texto 1.<br/>TIP: texto 2"></asp:TextBox>
```

Hope this help someone

Answer (score 0):

Grater than Jquery UI 1.10 is not support to use html tag inside of the title attribute because its not valid html.

So the alternative solution is to use tooltip content option.
Refer - http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-content

Answer (score 0):

Use

```html
&#013
```

There shouldn't be any ; character.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jquery-ui 1.11.4:

```
var tooltip = $.widget( "ui.tooltip", {
    version: "1.11.4",
    options: {
        content: function() {
            // support: IE<9, Opera in jQuery <1.7
            // .text() can't accept undefined, so coerce to a string
            var title = $( this ).attr( "title" ) || "";
            // Escape title, since we're going from an attribute to raw HTML
Replace-->  //return $( "<a>" ).text( title ).html();
by -->      return $( "<a>" ).html( title );
             },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AngularJS with Bootstrap UI Tolltip (uib-tooltip), has three versions of tool-tip:
```

*uib-tooltip, uib-tooltip-template and uib-tooltip-html*

```
- uib-tooltip takes only text and will escape any HTML provided
- uib-tooltip-html takes an expression that evaluates to an HTML string
- uib-tooltip-template takes a text that specifies the location of the template
```

*In my case, I opted for **uib-tooltip-html** and there are three parts to it:*

1. configuration
2. controller
3. HTML

**Example:**

```
(function(angular) {

//Step 1: configure $sceProvider - this allows the configuration of $sce service.

angular.module('myApp', ['uib.bootstrap'])
       .config(function($sceProvider) {
           $sceProvider.enabled(false);
       });

//Step 2: Set the tooltip content in the controller

angular.module('myApp')
       .controller('myController', myController);

myController.$inject = ['$sce'];

function myController($sce) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.tooltipContent = $sce.trustAsHtml('I am the first line <br /><br />' +
                                         'I am the second line-break');

    return vm;
}

 })(window.angular);

//Step 3: Use the tooltip in HTML (UI)

<div ng-controller="myController as get">
     <span uib-tooltip-html="get.tooltipContent">other Contents</span>
</div>
```

*For more information, please check [here](https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2017/03/24/angularjs-add-line-break-or-html-elements-in-angular-bootstrap-ui-tooltip/)*

Answer (score 0):

Using .html() instead of .text() worked for me. For example

```
.html("This is a first line." + "<br/>" + "This is a second line.")
```

Comment: this is not for title/tooltips. your code is for normal HTML content

Answer (score 0):

**Hi this code will work in all browser !!i used 
 for new line in chrome and safari and ul li for IE**

```
 function genarateMultiLIneCode(){
        var =values["a","b","c"];
        const liStart = '<li>';
              const liEnd = '</li>';
              const bullet = '&#8226; ';     
              var mergedString = ' ';
              const unOrderListStart='<ul>'
              const unOrderListEnd='</ul>'
              const fakeNewline = '&#013;&#010;';
              for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                   mergedString += liStart + bullet + values[i] + liEnd + fakeNewline;
              }
              const tempElement = document.createElement("div");
              tempElement.innerHTML = unOrderListStart + mergedString + unOrderListEnd;    
              return tempElement.innerText;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

This css will help you.

```
    .tooltip {
      word-break: break-all;
    }

or if you want in one line

    .tooltip-inner {
      max-width: 100%;
    }
```