# Web Tooltip "universally accepted" linebreak character?

Tags: html, firefox

I use \n to create a linebreak in web tooltip. This works in IE and in Chrome. But Firefox ignores it.

What will work universally as linebreak character in tooltip? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update**: This has been cleared up in [HTML5](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#the-title-attribute) using the title attribute. Now Firefox 12 supports it. Try this:

```
<span title="First line&#10;Second line">Test</span>
```

Bad news: Firefox does *not line break tooltips*. This is actually a non-standard html extension, ie a bug in MSIE that may cause problem with certain pages.

See [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=358452) on the firefox issue tracker.

Answer (score 3):

As of Firefox 12 they now support line breaks using the line feed HTML entity: `&#10;`

```
<span title="First line&#10;Second line">Test</span>
```

This works in IE and is correct according to the HTML5 spec for the [title attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#the-title-attribute-0).

Comment: &#10;  does not work in IE inside the title attribute of an anchor tag.  It just prints the characters &#10; instead.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox doesn't display multi-lines in tooltips.

Use tooltip script if you really want to customize it as you expected. 
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/tooltips-scripts-50-scripts-with-ajax-javascripts-css-tutorials/

Answer (score 0):

This works in mail messages `%0A` See [these google results for more information](http://www.google.nl/#sclient=psy&hl=nl&source=hp&q=%250A+linebreak&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=222c2db30f455ae4&biw=1366&bih=768).

Comment: This is true, yet not relevant for tool tips in html.