# "&#013;" doesn't produce a <br> on chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, browser, line-breaks

The code `&#013;` works to create a `<br>` in a tooltip in Firefox, like this:

```
<div title:"Line1&#013;Line2">hover me</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c46n4c71/

But on Chrome, it just displays as one line.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there another similar piece of code that works on both browsers?

Comment: It shows as two lines in my Chrome (42.0.2311.152 m)

Comment: @RickHitchcock In the jsfiddle??

Comment: Yes. In the fiddle. It shows two lines on hover in Chrome.

Comment: @Drakes Could the fact that I'm using Ubuntu affect anything? I thought browsers worked the exact same no matter the operating system...

Comment: @Drakes I'm using the exact same version, 42.0.2311.152. What's your operating system?

Comment: Post a screenshot of your hover.

Comment: @JoeMorano Can you please try this: `<div title="Line1&#10;Line2">hover me</div>`

Comment: @Drakes Ah, that one works, thanks! If you post it as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: @JoeMorano Done. See below.

Comment: I'm assuming `title:` is actually `title=`

Comment: Could've sworn earlier this week, &#013; worked fine in Chrome. Today I noticed it no longer did and had to change it to &#010; #strangerthings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, the "universally accepted" line break character is `&#10;`

```html
<div title="Line1&#10;Line2">Hover and see two lines</div>
```

Ref: [Web Tooltip "universally accepted" linebreak character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502054/web-tooltip-universally-accepted-linebreak-character)