# How to make Twitter Bootstrap tooltips have multiple lines?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently using the below function to create text that will be displayed using Bootstrap’s tooltip plugin. How come multiline tooltips only work with `<br>` and not `\n`? I prefer that there is not any HTML in my links’ title attributes.

What works

```
def tooltip(object)
  tooltip = ""
  object.each do |user|
    tooltip += "#{user.identifier}" + "<br>"
  end
  return tooltip
end
```

What I want

```
def tooltip(object)
   tooltip = ""
   object.each do |user|
     tooltip += "#{user.identifier}" + "\n"
   end
   return tooltip
 end
```

Comment: Do you understand the difference between \n and <br/> in HTML?

Comment: <br/> will work on html rendering side, while /n will only display your html code in new line

Comment: I was looking at some other websites and they have multiline tooltips without the br

Answer (score 277, accepted):

You can use `white-space:pre-wrap` on the tooltip. This will make the tooltip respect new lines. Lines will still wrap if they are longer than the default max-width of the container.

```
.tooltip-inner {
    white-space:pre-wrap;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chad/TSZSL/52/

If you want to prevent text from wrapping, do the following instead.

```
.tooltip-inner {
    white-space:pre;
    max-width:none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chad/TSZSL/53/

Neither of these will work with a `\n` in the html, they must actually be actual newlines. Alternatively, you can use encoded newlines `&#013;`, but that's probably even less desirable than using `<br>`'s.

Comment: Now how do you do that with a popover.

Comment: @aaa90210 you could try `.popover-content { white-space:pre-wrap; }`. Depending on your content, `.popover-content p { white-space:pre-wrap; }` or something similar, might look better.

Comment: Is it possible to show JSP variables in tooltip like this? I have tried `<a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="${aaa}
                       ${bbb}
                       ${ccc}"
                       class="example">Show</a>`. But it gives this: aaabbbccc (concatenated strings).

Comment: .tooltip-inner { white-space:pre-line;}  working for me.

Comment: pre-line worked for me - all others made text not align properly

Comment: Note that 013 doesn't work for newlines in case u are trying to use this type of character. I had to use &#10; instead

Answer (score 229):

You can use the html property: http://jsfiddle.net/UBr6c/

`My <a href="#" title="This is a<br />test...<br />or not" class="my_tooltip">Tooltip</a> test.`

```
$('.my_tooltip').tooltip({html: true})
```

Comment: You haven't checked `Bootstrap 2.0.2 (js only)` option in your jsFiddle, which makes it not working at initial run (open). Mark and save it, so other won't comply, that your example doesn't work.

Answer (score 61):

If you're using *Twitter Bootstrap* Tooltip on non-link element, you can specify, that you want a multi-line tooltip directly in HTML code, without Javascript, using just the `data` parameter:

```
<span rel="tooltip" data-html="true" data-original-title="1<br />2<br />3">5</span>
```

This is just an alternative version of *costales*' answer. All the glory goes to him! :]

Comment: Why do you say "non-link element"? I tried this on a link and it seemed to work fine.

Comment: Well... I don't remember! :] After five months, I think I was wrong. I also don't know, why it shouldn't be working on links. Sorry...

Comment: This one worked for me, specially if you are triggering tooltips with javascript, this will be loaded in the element itself, thanks !

Answer (score 15):

If you are using Angular UI Bootstrap, you can use tooltip with html syntax: `tooltip-html-unsafe`

e.g.
update to angular 1.2.10 & angular-ui-bootstrap 0.11: 
http://jsfiddle.net/aX2vR/1/

old one: http://jsfiddle.net/8LMwz/1/

Answer (score 2):

In Angular UI Bootstrap 0.13.X, tooltip-html-unsafe has been deprecated. You should now use tooltip-html and $sce.trustAsHtml() to accomplish a tooltip with html.

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/e31fcf0fcb06580064d1e6375dbedb69f1c95f25

```
<a href="#" tooltip-html="htmlTooltip">Check me out!</a>

$scope.htmlTooltip = $sce.trustAsHtml('I\'ve been made <b>bold</b>!');
```

Answer (score 1):

The CSS solution for Angular Bootstrap is

```
::ng-deep .tooltip-inner {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

No need to use a parent element or class selector if you don't need to restrict it's use.
Copy/Pasta, and this rule will apply to all sub-components