# How to make Bootstrap 4 popovers scrollable

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I saw another question like this, but the answer didn't work for me and I'm not sure why. Why isn't my popover content scrolling when over 50px? Also side question: in my variable 'a', my newlines aren't working within the popover. Anyone know why?

```js
var a = "hello \n hello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \n hello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \nhello \n";
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
});

$("#button1").attr('data-content', a);
```

```css
.popover-content {
  height: 10px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.4/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button id="button1" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="Hello">Click to toggle popover</button>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're targeting the wrong class. The correct class is `popover-body`:

```
.popover-body {
    height: 50px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    white-space:pre-wrap;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gx27dbv3/

Comment: That worked! Do you have any idea why the \n characters didn't work in the 'a' variable?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338780/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-tooltips-have-multiple-lines

Comment: This worked (from the link you provided): .popover-body {
            white-space:pre-wrap;
            }

Comment: Cool! I added that into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the **height of the popover relative** to the content and only use a **max-height**. It works with display: flex on the wrapper.

```
.popover {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; 
    max-height: 1000px;
    /** Do not define an overflow on the wrapper or your arrow to the element will disapear */
}
.popover-body {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Consider this: from the moment your page gets smaller then max-height defined above , then set max-height to 99%.

```
@media screen and (max-height: 1000px) {
    .popover {
        max-height: 99%;
    }
}
```

I tried everything for 5 hours and this is the only solution that really worked