# How to prevent Bootstrap from breaking lines automatically in popovers

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I want to add a tooltip with Bootstrap's popover like this:

```
<ul>
     <li>Entry 1 ....................................................................</li>
     <li>Entry 2 ....................................................................</li>
     <li>Entry 3 ....................................................................</li>
</ul>
```

However, Bootstrap will break the line automatically at some point. I have set `html: true` and tried to add a div element:

```
<div style="word-break: keep-all>
<ul>
     <li style="word-break: keep-all"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

but it still breaks the line.
Is it possible to avoid automatically line breaks and maybe add a horizontal scrollbar instead? How can I even specify the width of the tooltip area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to add an `overflow-x: scroll;` to your `.popover-content` class, as well as a `white-space: nowrap` to each `li`.

https://jsfiddle.net/nrpe1m05/

Comment: For me it only worked with popover-body as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50915309/1221159

Comment: @Baradé it must depend on the version you're using, glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
<ul>
   <li style="white-space: nowrap"></li> 
</ul>
```

`white-space: nowrap` will force the content to be all in one line.