# Add line break to tooltip in Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 and added a tooltip to my div. I've tried using < br > \n and &#013; to create the new line. Would it be a problem with the Bootstrap stopping me?

```
<div class="content show-tooltip" data-placement="top" 
     data-original-title="1st line of text <br> 2nd line of text">
```

Answer (score 244, accepted):

You need to add `data-html="true"` to the markup..

```
<div class="content show-tooltip" data-html="true" data-placement="top" 
     title="1st line of text <br> 2nd line of text">
```

Working demo: https://codeply.com/p/C8083WXo5Z

Comment: This is great thanks. Are there docs available on these data attributes?

Comment: I found the docs here (did they move?): http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-options

Comment: thanks for this, i dont see data-html="true" anywhere in the docs tho

Comment: how can I activate it from javascript?

Comment: For anyone still looking 6 years later, you can find the data attribute documentation for v3.4 [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#tooltips-options)

Comment: Could you explain why you need to add data-html="true", thanks.

Comment: @Chris - Read the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#tooltips-options).. look at the "html" option

Comment: For anyone on Bootstrap v5: `data-bs-html="true"`

Answer (score 4):

In the Title use this code to break the line:

HTML

```
...title="- Item 1 &#013; - Item 2 &#013;"
```

CSS

```
.ui-tooltip {
    /* tooltip container box */
    white-space: pre-line;
}

.ui-tooltip-content {
    /* tooltip content */
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

Comment: This works, but this adds a space character at the start of my new line. It seems &#10; do the same, but without this front space character.