# Bootstrap 4 tooltip text formatting

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have been trying to make tooltips on my site look nice and have recently come across the tooltips on Godaddy.com which I would love to be able to replicate the text formating on:
[image: Godaddy Tooltip]

Currently my own tooltips look like this:
[image]
This is my current code, it is very important that the tooltip appears when hovering over an image(looks messy I know but please ignore that):

```
<img src="image URL here" width="20" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="A short description of your project/solution (max 250 characters), will only be displayed on the home screen, not in your post! If you do not wish to use this leave 'None'">
```

What I am primarily trying to do is to be able to create new lines with in the Tooltip.

Any suggestions would be much appriciated!

Comment: as you say in the second image it is already creating new line isn't it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19001875/1675954

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add line break to tooltip in Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001766/add-line-break-to-tooltip-in-bootstrap-3)

Comment: @Rasmus Baj, did my answer worked for you?

Comment: @Manjuboyz Unfortunetly not. When I try to deploy your solution in my project this code does not result in anything, might be conflicting with some of the Bootstrap stuff.

Comment: Hmmm strange! never happened to me, have been using this for every instance.

Comment: @Manjuboyz Yes very, when I use the code I can see it in the inspecter but nothing appears on the page itself exept for some whitespace where the element is placed.
But thanks for the help I appriciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding

```
data-html="true"
```

This allowed me to use `<br/>`  in the title text

The final code snippet:

```
<img src="image URL here" width="20" data-html="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="A short description of your project/solution (max 250 characters), will only be displayed on the home screen, not in your post! <br/> If you do not wish to use this leave 'None'">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

you can add new line by adding `<br />` between the contents, that should work for you.

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 220px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  text-align: justify;
  /* This is what you need */
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
   <div class="tooltip">Hover me
  <span class="tooltiptext">A short description of your project/solution (max 250 characters), will only be displayed on the home screen. <br /> <br /> Second para not in your post! If you do not wish to use this leave 'None</span>
</div>
```