# The line-break in the tool tip doesn't wok

Tags: html, escaping, line-breaks

How to make a line break within a tool tip? this way doesn't seem to work:

```
<span title="First line.<br>Second line.">
   <a href="URL">
   <img src="URL" alt="download file"></a></span>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340802/add-line-break-within-tooltips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `&#10;` instead of `<br>`

```
<span title="First line.&#10;Second line.">
<a href="URL">
<img src="URL" alt="download file"></a></span>
```

working demo http://jsfiddle.net/L6xsso3t/5/