# Display string with line break

Tags: javascript, html

I need to display string with line break.

I have object:

```
"test": {
    "test1": 5,
    "test2": 6
 }
```

Now I need display something like this:

```
test1 - 5
test2 - 6
```

So I use:

```
$scope.displayString = _.keys(test).map(function(key) {
    return (key + '-' + test[key])
}).join('\n')
```

But on view I have still string in one line, like:

```
test1 - 5 test2 - 6
```

It looks like I replace comma for one space, but I would like to have line break. How can I solve it? Thanks for any tip!

I don't want to use jQuery, I want pass $scope.displayString to my html (for tooltip).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Line break in html with \`\n\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325414/line-break-in-html-with-n)

Comment: In html you must use '<br>' instead of '\n'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a new line in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758161/how-do-i-create-a-new-line-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.displayString = _.keys(test).map(function(key) {
   return (key + '-' + test[key] + '\n')
})
```

or

```
$scope.displayString = _.keys(test).map(key => key + '-' + test[key] + '\n')
```

Comment: it will return an Array[ ], if you are not using the `.join()`

Answer (score 0):

You must use br/ in Html for line break.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add `<br>` instead of \n if displaying to html

```js
$("#id1").html("test 1 "+"<br>"+" test 2");
$("#id2").html("test 1 "+"\n"+" test 2");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id1"></div>
<hr>
<div id="id2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `join("<br />")` instead of `join("\n")` and also use `html()` function.

```js
let object = {
  "test": {
    "test1": 5,
    "test2": 6
  }
}, 
text = Object.keys(object.test).map(function(key) {
  return (key + '-' + object.test[key])
}).join("<br />");

$('#showHere').html(text)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id='showHere'>

</p>
```

Comment: How can I avoid using jQuery?

Comment: Are you using AngularJS? @emka26

Comment: Yes, and I want to pass $scope.displayString to html (for tooltip)

Comment: Did you try `angular.element('#showHere').html(text)` instead? @emka26

Comment: But I need pass it for tooltip like this: <tooltip='{{displayString}}'></tooltip>.

Comment: tooltip is a directive? Create a working example on codepen. @emka26

Comment: Yes, tooltip is a directive. Can't create codepen, because it's a part of huge project and it's many dependecies. But fact is that I must pass string of characters to directive in html and I want to have it with line break.

Comment: Maybe using `&#013;` according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340802/add-line-break-within-tooltips) helps. I can not figure out how that directive works, so I can't  help more. @emka26