# Tooltip: ngbTooltip doesn't accept a new line

Tags: angular

I want to add a line break inside my tool tip but it's not working, i tried everything from `\n`, `<br>`, `&013;/ &#13`

Here is my code:

```
<a>
 <img class="rounded-circle d-inline-block" src="{{content.image}}"  
 triggers="click" [autoClose]="true" ngbTooltip="{{content.email}} <br> 
 {{content.tel}}">
</a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add line break within tooltips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340802/add-line-break-within-tooltips)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use `ng-template` here and it would look like below. This should give you the list effect you are looking for. This is what I opted for and worked well.

[Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#the-ng-template)

```
<ng-template #list>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
      <span>{{ content.email}}</span>
      <span>{{ content.tel}}</span>
    </div>
</ng-template>


 <img class="rounded-circle d-inline-block" src="{{content.image}}"  
 triggers="click" [autoClose]="true" [ngbTooltip]="list">
```

Normal css for `class="d-flex flex-column"` outside of bootstrap would be

```
.example {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

[explanation found here for flex css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction)

Comment: Example needs updating as you're opening with <span> but closing with </td>

Comment: No worries, happy to help :-)